# Apply marquee selection to multiple layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, selections

I have Photoshop documents with many layers, some over 100.

I need to delete a feathered selection on **all** layers without having to manually select each layer, reapply the selection, hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

Is this possible?

Comment: Selections aren't tied to *any* single layer. Can you explain what you mean by "apply selection"?

Comment: I need to delete a feathered selection on ALL layers without having to manually select each layer , reapply the selection, hit DELETE key.

Comment: Just group all the layers and apply a layer mask?

Comment: @Ovaryraptor that looks suspiciously like an answer `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your *marquee* selection, it automatically applies to any layer you select.

You can simply keep selecting each layer (Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>/<kbd>]</kbd> to move down/up layers) and just hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> (it'll go pretty quickly)

[image]

<sup>Notice the lines getting removed from each layer.</sup>

---

You can even turn it into an action and add a hotkey to do it for you (If you have many documents it'll be helpful - just make the selection, hit the hotkey and wallah-- it's done)

<sub>(You will have to do it fully once to *create* the action)</sub>

If it's just **1 doc** with 100 layers, record yourself doing it to a few layers and then just hit the hotkey a few times.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is to simplify your file first, and then apply the feathering.
Creating groups or file duplicates helps^. after duplicating them (the Group and/or the image) you can merge grouped sections and apply special filters, etc. *(in this case feathering)* to the merged group.

The groups and duplicates can also help you restore any portion of the file you may not be able to go back in your history to reclaim.

(*^Layers / select layers [keep them together] Cntrl G.) & (Image - Duplicate)*

You may begin to form groups naturally as you work. They make multi tasking on multiple layers, like your example, easier.

Comment: Simplifying is good `:)`. You might want to answer the actual question being posed though -- how to apply a feathered selection to all layers. `:)` This isn't really an answer as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I might have is to link the layers that need the feather applied. I hope this helps, sorry if it doesn’t.